# Getting issue bootstrap left side menu baar, want to add next more sub menu items

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<li class="drop-menu-tab">
    <a class="dropmenu" ><i class="icon-folder-close-alt"></i><span> Employee</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="submenu" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>emp/fulltime"><i class="icon-edit"></i><span class="hidden-tablet">Full Time</span></a></li>                                  
            <li id="mainmenulink"><a class="submenu" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>emp/parttime"><i class="icon-edit"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Part Time</span></a></li>
        </ul>   
</li>
```

**I have to add next more sub menus..**

For ex.

```
Employee > Full Time > Day Shift
Employee > Full Time > Night Shift
```

I tried this with multiple ways.. but getting proper tabs open close.. please suggest possible script

FYI: Using "Bootstrap v2.3.1"

Answer (score -1):

You have an typo error while writing `<span>` you have written it as `<spanc>`

Change it to

```
<span> Employee</span>
```

**And you can have the desired output by**

```css
li{
  list-style: none;
}
ol.breadcrumb li+li:before {
  padding: 8px;
  color: black;
  content: "\003e";
}
```

```html
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class=""><a href="#">Employee </a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">Full Time</a></li>
    <li class="" aria-current="page">Day Shift</li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class=""><a href="#">Employee </a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">Full Time</a></li>
    <li class="" aria-current="page">Night Shift</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please can you explain your error in more detailed way so that i can give you a better solution

Comment: corected spell mistake @Kunal Raut.. I have to one more next submenu item as given.. but I am unable

Comment: I got you @HemantP please check out my edited answer.

Comment: I got me wrong.. at the start I have provided my left side bar menu structure in <ul><li> format. I that menu I have to add next sub menu with <ul><li> format itself. Which have you implemented, I just given submenu struture that is not have to implement same as that example. editing question!

Comment: Look this is totally worng and unfair too you cannot change the question later i have answered your question asked correctly if you have to get another please ask another question.

Comment: you took wrong understanding bro.. sry for unsufficient question details

Comment: I gave you the exact output you were looking for and wrong understanding like what?

Comment: Ok now according to the rule please accept this answer and ask a new one i'll help you on that or else i will have to flag your question.